# Spring JAXWS Best practice with SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter - JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws

I'm learning Spring from a book called "Spring 4 in action".
I'm actually doing the webservice part; in particular "Publishing and consuming web services".

Following the book, I've been able to setup a **JAX-WS web service** in this way:

**Server Side**:

`SpittrServiceImpl`: Class that exposes the JAX-WS Service

```
@Component
@WebService(serviceName="SpittrService")
public class SpittrServiceImpl {


    @Autowired
    SpitterRepository spitterRepository;

    @Autowired
    SpittleRepository spittleRepository;

    @WebMethod
    public String helloService() { return "Hello world"; }

    @WebMethod
    public Spitter showSpitterProfile(String username) {
        Spitter spitter = spitterRepository.findByUsername(username);
        spitter.setSpittleList(new ArrayList<>());
        System.out.println("SERVER SIDE - showSpitterProfile: " + spitter.toString());
        return spitter;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public Spittle findSpittleById(long spittleId) {
        Spittle spittle = spittleRepository.findById(spittleId);
        System.out.println("SERVER SIDE - findSpittleById: " + spittle.toString());
        return spittle;
    }
}
```

`JAXWSConfig`: Class that configures the JAXWS Service

```
@Configuration
public class JAXWSConfig {

    @Bean
    public SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter jaxWsExporter() {
        SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter exporter = new SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter();
        exporter.setBaseAddress("http://localhost:8888/services/");
        return exporter;
    }
}
```

This creates the **WSDL** that i report at the end.

On the **Client side**, we have the following classes:

`ClientConfig`: Class that returns the proxy to the WSDL created by the server side

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"spittrClient", "spittr"})
public class ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean spittrService() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("CREATING JAX-WS CONNECTION...");
        JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean proxy = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean();
        proxy.setWsdlDocumentUrl(new URL("http://localhost:8888/services/SpittrService?wsdl"));
        proxy.setServiceName("SpittrService");
        proxy.setPortName("SpittrServiceImplPort");
        proxy.setServiceInterface(SpittrService.class);
        proxy.setNamespaceUri("http://jaxws.remoting.spittr/");
        System.out.println("JAX-WS CONNECTION CREATED");
        return proxy;
    }
}
```

`SpittrService`: Interface that exposed the methods of service offered by the WSDL

```
@WebService(serviceName = "SpittrService")
public interface SpittrService {

    @WebMethod
    String helloService();

    @WebMethod
    Spitter showSpitterProfile(String username);

    @WebMethod
    Spittle findSpittleById(long spittleId);

}
```

`Client`: Class that calls the services offered by the Server through JAX-WS
@Component
public class Client {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Run the Client class directly from main method

        System.out.println("CLIENT MAIN");
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ClientConfig.class);

        SpittrService spittrService = (SpittrService) ctx.getBean(SpittrService.class);
        Spitter spitter = spittrService.showSpitterProfile("PyroSandro");
        System.out.println("SPITTER CALLED BY JAX-WS: " + spitter.toString());

        Spittle spittle = spittrService.findSpittleById(111);
        System.out.println("SPITTLE CALLED BY JAX-WS: " + spittle.toString());

    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but I don't like the implementation.
I thought I should have implemented the interface `SpittrService` (which is on client side) also on server side and the class `SpittrServiceImpl` had to implement its methods.
But if I create the `SpittrService` interface and move there the annotations `@WebService` and `@WebMethod` from the `SpittrServiceImpl`, it stops working.

Another option is the that the same annotations `@WebService` and `@WebMethod` are placed on both `SpittrService` interface and `SpittrServiceImpl` class, but I don't know if this is a good practice (but it works).

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Here I report the **WSDL** created by the Server Side:

```xml
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://jaxws.remoting.spittr/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="SpittrService" targetNamespace="http://jaxws.remoting.spittr/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://jaxws.remoting.spittr/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://jaxws.remoting.spittr/" version="1.0">
            <xs:element name="findSpittleById" type="tns:findSpittleById"/>
            <xs:element name="findSpittleByIdResponse" type="tns:findSpittleByIdResponse"/>
            <xs:element name="helloService" type="tns:helloService"/>
            <xs:element name="helloServiceResponse" type="tns:helloServiceResponse"/>
            <xs:element name="showSpitterProfile" type="tns:showSpitterProfile"/>
            <xs:element name="showSpitterProfileResponse" type="tns:showSpitterProfileResponse"/>
            <xs:complexType name="helloService">
                <xs:sequence/>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="helloServiceResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="showSpitterProfile">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="showSpitterProfileResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:spitter"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="spitter">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="username" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="findSpittleById">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="arg0" type="xs:long"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="findSpittleByIdResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:spittle"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="spittle">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:long"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="latitude" type="xs:double"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="longitude" type="xs:double"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="spitter" type="tns:spitter"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="time" type="xs:dateTime"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="helloService">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:helloService" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="showSpitterProfileResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:showSpitterProfileResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="showSpitterProfile">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:showSpitterProfile" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="findSpittleById">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:findSpittleById" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="findSpittleByIdResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:findSpittleByIdResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="helloServiceResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:helloServiceResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="SpittrServiceImpl">
        <wsdl:operation name="helloService">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:helloService" name="helloService"> </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:helloServiceResponse" name="helloServiceResponse"> </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="showSpitterProfile">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:showSpitterProfile" name="showSpitterProfile"> </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:showSpitterProfileResponse" name="showSpitterProfileResponse"> </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="findSpittleById">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:findSpittleById" name="findSpittleById"> </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:findSpittleByIdResponse" name="findSpittleByIdResponse"> </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="SpittrServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:SpittrServiceImpl">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="helloService">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="helloService">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="helloServiceResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="showSpitterProfile">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="showSpitterProfile">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="showSpitterProfileResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="findSpittleById">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="findSpittleById">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="findSpittleByIdResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SpittrService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:SpittrServiceSoapBinding" name="SpittrServiceImplPort">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8888/services/SpittrService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: You shouldn't. When you are working with a webservice the contract is the WSDL. You won't get a Java interface from the party serving that webservice. So the things on the client and server should be separated and don't try to reuse things.

Comment: So, once I've finished to setup ClientConfig class as the book suggest (with JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean), how should I implement the Client class if not using the interface? In other words, how can I call/use the web methods in the client?